# Updating the Linux Kernel - Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: kernel, 18.10

I'm trying to upgrade my linux kernel to 4.20, and am currently on 4.18:

```
uname -a => Linux ubuntu 4.18.0-15-generic #16-Ubuntu SMP Thu Feb 7 10:56:39 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I've tried:

```
sudo apt install linux-image-generic
sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade && sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt clean
```

Which all seem to leave me at 4.18. Is there any way to explicitly tell Ubuntu to upgrade the Linux Kernel? I've tried most the answers I can find online with no joy

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you want to upgrade to 4.20? Do you know that the 4.20 kernel is not officially supported by Ubuntu?

Comment: I did not to be honest... my end result is installing some drivers which are apparently included in that kernel so it's probably best for me to figure out how to install the drivers directly - thanks for the response

Comment: You can install the 4.20 using UKUU, but it is nether supported, nor recommended.

Comment: I'll ask separately for help with the drivers then :)